# Is it normal to have an upward sloping precision/recall curve?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, precision-recall

I keep getting precision/recall curves that look like this when using scikit learns's `precision_recall_curve` function and using the result from `classifier.predict_proba(X)[:,1]` as the 'scores' parameter.  (Note: I didn't include what classifier I am using because I keep seeing this upward curve again and again with different classifiers.  This particular curve comes from a logistic regression model).

Does it make sense to have an upward sloping precision recall curve as shown in the picture above?  how am I to interpret such a curve?
[image]

[I've checked out this answer about horizontal curves](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161314/can-a-precision-recall-curve-or-a-roc-curve-be-horizontal), but this is a very different situation.  That one deals with a horizontal, 100% precision curve, which makes more intuitive sense to me.  But this?  This does not.